# How to find $p$ such that $A$ is independent of $c$.

Tags: calculus

Let A be the area of the triangle formed by x-axis, y-axis and the tangent line of $y=x^p$ ($p<0$) at $x=c$. Find $p$ such that $A$ is independent of $c$.

P.S What does "$A$ is independent of $c$" mean?

Comment: You should get $p=-1$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** Find the first derivative $f'$ of $f\colon x\mapsto x^p$ and using it the exact tangent line equation $y=mx+b$ through the point $(c,f(c))$.
Find the intercepts $(x_0,0)$ and $(0,y_0)$ of that line.
Then the area is $A=\frac 12 x_0 y_0$.
This will be an expression that depends on the givens $c$ and $p$.
For some $p$, the expression can be simplified in such a manner that it does not involve $c$ at all, i.e. for that $p$, $A$ is independent of $c$.